# C# String Manipulation for different characters

Tags: c#, string

how can I find each distinct char in a string and display it in a new line for example:

```
string ex = "aabbbbchhhhaaaacc";
```

becomes:

```
a: aaaaaa
b: bbbb
c: ccc
h: hhhh
```

I know I have to used new distinctn string and loop through each char in the string but not sure how to proceed.

```
string answer = new String(input.Distinct().ToArray());
                foreach (char c in answer)
                {
                   //what code goes here?
                }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
void Main()
{
    string ex = "aabbbbchhhhaaaacc";
    var chars = ex.ToCharArray().Distinct();
    foreach (var c in chars)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", c, new String(c, ex.Where(ch => ch == c).Count()));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
a: aaaaaa
b: bbbb
c: ccc
h: hhhh
```

Comment: +1 for being the first one that actually did was was asked for.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a regular expression:

```
void Main()
{
    string ex = "aabbbbchhhhaaaacc";
    var re = new Regex(@"(.)\1*");
    var sequences =
        from Match ma in re.Matches(ex)
        let value = ma.Value
        group value by value[0] into g
        select g.Aggregate((s1, s2) => s1 + s2);

    foreach (var sequence in sequences)
        Debug.WriteLine(sequence);
}
```

You can test this in [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) and it'll output exactly what you want.

Here's an explanation of the expression:

```
(.)\1*
^-^^-^
 |  |
 |  +- says "0 or more times of the exact same character as in group 1"
 +- first group
```

The LINQ query will do this:

1. Find each distinct occurence of the characters
2. Pick out the first (possibly the only) character of this sequence
3. Group all the occurances by their first character (so that all sequences of "a"'s is in one group)
4. Aggregate each group together to get each complete sequence

Now, the above solution works though there are other ways to do this. If the patterns to detect was a bit more complicated than just "the same character N times", then a regular expression might be the best way.

However, what you can do is exploit that fact, that it's the same character:

```
void Main()
{
    string ex = "aabbbbchhhhaaaacc";
    var groups = ex
        .ToCharArray()
        .GroupBy(c => c);

    foreach (var group in groups)
        Debug.WriteLine(new string(group.Key, group.Count()));
}
```

This will simply create groups containing all occurences of each character, where `group.Key` is the character and `group.Count()` is the length, and then we can simply construct new strings from each group.

Comment: I feel like a muppet now for trying to do a solution that looped through the characters and just looked for when the character changed. Nice one!

Comment: Look carefully to the edits on the question, he want to join all cases for tha same character

Comment: Please find updated, complicated it a bit I need to count for each distinct char

Comment: Incidentally, no parentheses needed around `\1`.

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect your edits, but please know that answering towards a moving target is never going to work well here on Stack Overflow. Please put more thought into the initial question the next time.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Ok, I wasn't sure about that so I didn't bother testing it without. Edited to reflect this. Thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

```
string ex = "aabbbbchhhh";
var answer = ex.GroupBy(r => r);
foreach (var z in answer)
{
  Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}",z.Key,new String(z.Key,z.Count()));
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: +1 for probably the most brief and elegant linq solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
string ex = "aabbbbchhhhaaaacc";
var result = ex.Distinct().ToDictionary(k => k, v => new string(v, ex.Count(c => c == v)));
foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Key + ": " + item.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my take on the problem:

```
void Main()
{
    string input = "aabbbbchhhhaaaacc";
    var dic = new Dictionary<char, int>();
    foreach (char c in input)
    {
        if (dic.ContainsKey(c))
        {
            dic[c]++;
        }
        else
        {
            dic[c] = 1;
        }
    }
    foreach (var item in dic)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", item.Key, new string(item.Key, item.Value));
    }
}
```

Here I'm storing how many times you see each character in the dictionary, the dictionary is then used to build the output.

Note 1: this approach also has the adventage of doing a single pass on the string, methods using Distinct and stuff will do two or more passes on the string, making the whole process slower.

Note 2: Also, this method doesn't require Linq, in fact, it will happily work on .Net 2.0.

Note 3: Compiled and tested on LinqPad.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Ahmed KRAIEM, but this should be faster since it doesn't perform a distinct and a count for each character. (Of course, until you have strings that are megabytes in length, it doesn't really matter :))

```
string ex = "aabbbbchhhhaaaacc";
foreach (var kvPair in ex.GroupBy(x => x).Select(g => new { Key = g.Key, Val = new string(g.Key, g.Count()) })) {
    Console.WriteLine(kvPair.Key + ": " + kvPair.Val);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just use distinct on the string itself.

```
        string ex = "aabbbbchhhhaaaacc";
        ex.GroupBy(c => c).ToList().ForEach(group => Console.WriteLine( group.Key + " : " + group.Count()));
```

Comment: This just shows a distinct list of the characters used, not the frequency of them in the source string.

Comment: You're right, PhonicUK. I should have read the question a lot better. I updated the code to fit give the proper output.